# How to avoid having to run "setup:upgrade" and "static deploy" each time a change is made?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Whenever i make changes in knockout.js files and html file inside web folder. I have to run "setup:upgrade" and "static deploy" again. Is there any solution to avoid doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update Answer:
Keep the deployment mode as Developer and do not run static-content deploy command, this will make sure all your html and js files will be created a symlinks and any changes done on main file will automatically reflect in pub/static files.

OLD answer
Delete the Specific File Which you are modifying from Pub/Static Folder which is generated during the Initial deployment .

Once Deleted reload the site so the new static file will be created with new contents

Comment: Yes it's works...

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in websites that run in production mode

Comment: development shouldn't be done in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - that is native flow of Magento 2 whenever you are doing any changes in JS file or CSS file you must have to run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f** command.

For upgrade command - AKAIK you don't need to run each and every time when you change JS or HTML file. Upgrade command is only used when you are installing any new modules , and you might have database related changes in your existing module by **Install/Upgrade Schema script**.

So you don't need to run setup:upgrade command each time.

> **But for Assets like JS and CSS - This is native flow as assets are**
>   **always served from pub/static directory so you must need to run that**
>   **command**.

Comment: upgrade command is need to clean static files.

Comment: because of your command i deleted .htaccess file in pub/static which created me lots of problem.

Comment: @avesh - ohh - yes you are correct , actually here we have done server level configuration where .htaccess is not removed - any way you resolved your issue ?

Comment: No man. Having same. I have to run those commands.

Comment: As i am new to magento 2 can i get tutorials on it?

Comment: @avesh - Yes magento 2 itself have very good documentation for learners here is the link - http://devdocs.magento.com/

Comment: Apart from that documentation is there anything else ? That is very complex for beginner like me.

Comment: @avesh - Yes there are lots of available - can you please let me know what exactly you want to learn i can find very good tutorial to you

Comment: about UI Components